# How do i find the number of children elements with a specific class with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a row that is auto populated with data from an api. Each result from the api is stored in a div which is created with js as well and then a class is appended to it.

I then have a filter connected to a search box that filters through the results and shows the relevant data. The divs that do not have the search query are assigned a new class "hide" which hides them. Whenever a search is performed, I want to search through the populated row and find out how many divs have the class of "hide" but I can't seem to wrap my head around a working solution yet.

Here's what the code structure looks like

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="data"></div>
   <div class="data"></div>
   <div class="data"></div>
   <div class="data hide"></div>     <!-- this is what itll look like for hidden divs -->
   <div class="data hide"></div>
</div>
```

Can I use **childelementcount** in addition to **classlist.contains()** in order to solve this? Or what's a walkaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to tackle this is to make use of [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
var list = document.getElementById('list');

var count = list.querySelectorAll('.data.hide').length;

console.log(count);
```

Please note that I added an `id` to the `row` element so that I could access it easier:

```html
<div id="list" class="row">
   <div class="data"></div>
   <div class="data"></div>
   <div class="data"></div>
   <div class="data hide"></div> 
   <div class="data hide"></div>
</div>
```

Here's a [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qywo9x3n/2/) for your quick reference.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks @matt ! I completely forgot I could use the length property on that. Appreciate the help :)